# Computer Systems onboard Europa Clipper

Tags: flight-computer, computer, europa-clipper

Is known which Computers Europa Clipper will be using? I'm guessing it will be RAD750 again, but I couldn't find any official sources.

Thanks for the help

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7943832 says " the RAD-750 based Command and Data Handling (CDH) subsystem ". But not more information or a citation that could make up an answer.

Comment: https://www.ghs.com/customers/jpl_europa.html also suggests a 750